# Do any Star Wars planets have multiple settlements/cities?

Tags: star-wars

Are there any planets in the Star Wars universe that have multiple settlements?

It seems every time anyone lands on a planet they immediately go to a major 'settlement' (city, village, etc.) and whenever they need to escape they jump to space instead of trying to find a different place on the planet.

Comment: Tatooine? Mos Eisley, Mos Espa, etc.

Comment: Naboo: Theed, Otoh Gunga, Lake Country.

Comment: @Null Anchorhead, Toche Station

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple instances of planets that have multiple settlements, towns, or cities. Tatooine has been mentioned alread. Naboo has Theed, Otoh Gunga, and the Lake Country.

However, the true question here is why characters choose to leave the planet when on the run instead of attempting to hide out in a settlement/town on the same planet. The fact is, they do both. The Gungans abandoned Otoh Gunga and go to The Sacred Place when under attack by the Trade Federation.

That said, when faced with a threat that can track you wherever you go in 'normal' space, Hyperspace is the only option. This is why most characters will leave a planet and/or entire system in order to escape a foe.

Comment: About that not being able to track you in Hyperspace thing ..

Comment: Well, until recently that was the way to shake a tail...

Answer (score 5):

On Tatooine, there are multiple settlements.  In *The Phantom Menace,* Qui-Gon specifically mentions multiple settlements when they arrive on the planet.  At a minimum, the larger communities include Mos Eisley and Mos Espa, as well as smaller places like Anchorhead.